# Facebook custom share url with custom parameters...works in preview but broken on FB

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, share

I was trying to create a share button that you can see on this page. There are different products and a custom link to share any item on their own. The store has been personalized with the method ... sharer / sharer.php? Etc.

Below is one of many links. The problem appears after you have shared the article on Facebook: the description does not appear, nor will the image and the title! Why?
Thanks!

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=[PROMO]%20Scopri%20questa%20fantastica%20promozione%20natalizia!&p[url]=http://contat.eu/facebook/vtour/fan.html&p[summary]=Spendi%20almeno%20100%20€%20sulla%20nuova%20collezione%20autunno/inverno%202013%20di%20Denny%20Rose%20oppure%20soprabito%20della%20nuova%20collezione%202013%20tra%20quelli%20illustrati%20e%20riceverai%20un%20completino%20intimo%20in%20regalo%20oppure%20uno%20sconto%20del%2050%%20sui%20capi%20di%20grandi%20marchi%20delle%20collezioni%20precedenti.%20Ma%20le%20sorprese%20non%20finiscono%20qui…%20tante%20borse,%20scarpe%20ed%20intimo%20a%20prezzi%20sbalorditivi.Descrizione&p[images][0]=http://contat.eu/facebook/vtour/img/mod/sm/diva-abbigliamento12.png
```

I look for some answers or suggestions! I'm online 12/24h ^ ^

Comment: Up! Is that an Facebook bug...?

Comment: The share dialog will not take additional parameters any more, _only_ the URL. All other info it takes from the OG meta tags on the URL shared. If you want to give that additional info yourself, you will have to use the Feed dialog, which still accepts them.

Comment: Thanks :) How i can rate your answer?

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The share dialog will not take additional parameters any more, only the URL. All other info it takes from the OG meta tags on the URL shared.

If you want to give that additional info yourself, you will have to use the [Feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), which still accepts them.